# How to create a custom Docker image by applying a custom patch to a file without having status 'Exited (0)'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, customization, docker-image

I am using a PhpIPAM Docker image and I use docker-compose to run my containers (https://hub.docker.com/r/pierrecdn/phpipam). I'm in a Windows environment.

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.3"

services:
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:5.6'
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
        volumes:
            - 'D:/Docker/phpIPAM/mysql-db:/var/lib/mysql'
    ipam:
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        image: pierrecdn/phpipam
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_USER=root
            - MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
            - MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_HOST=mysql
        ports:
            - "6080:80"
            - "6025:25"
            - "6022:22"
```

When I launch the command:

```
PS D:\Docker\phpIPAM> docker-compose up
```

All is working fine, my 2 containers are correctly running and I can work on the app.

```
1974e242966a        pierrecdn/phpipam   "docker-php-entrypoi…"   40 seconds ago      Up 38 seconds       0.0.0.0:6022->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6025->25/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6080->80/tcp   phpipam_ipam_1
6a638b4d1422        mysql:5.6           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   42 seconds ago      Up 39 seconds       3306/tcp                                                           phpipam_mysql_1
```

---

**N**ow I would like to customize PhpIPAM and apply a patch to a specific file. Actually I just replace the file in the image by the patched one (note: the patch is ok, I tested it in a running container).

So in a new folder I-:

1. copied my patched file of PhpIPAM
2. copied and adapt my docker-compose.yml file to build the new image
3. created a docker file named 'phpipam2440' with the operation to replace a file by my new patched file

Here is my new docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.3"

services:
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:5.6'
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
        volumes:
            - 'D:/Docker/phpIPAM/mysql-db:/var/lib/mysql'
    ipam2440:
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./phpipam2440
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_USER=root
            - MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
            - MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_HOST=mysql
        ports:
            - "6080:80"
            - "6025:25"
            - "6022:22"
        tty: true
```

and here is my docker file 'phpipam2440'

```
FROM pierrecdn/phpipam 

ADD class.Common.php /var/www/html/functions/classes/

CMD ["echo","Patch Fix #2440 applied"]
```

Now when I run

```
PS D:\Docker\phpIPAM\patch-2440> docker-compose up
```

Here is the result

```
2e22a2de7d28        patch-2440_ipam2440   "docker-php-entrypoi…"   55 seconds ago      Exited (0) 53 seconds ago                       patch-2440_ipam2440_1
c65d2cd5eadf        mysql:5.6             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   56 seconds ago      Up 55 seconds               3306/tcp            patch-2440_mysql_1
```

The container from my custom image is 'Exited' with code 0.

That mean all went well and the container has reach "the end of what it had to do".

However I used the option "tty: true" in my docker-compose and this should prevent my container to Exit.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thx

PS: For info here is the complete output of the docker-compose command:

```
PS D:\Docker\phpIPAM\patch-2440> docker-compose up
Creating network "patch-2440_default" with the default driver
Building ipam2440
Step 1/3 : FROM pierrecdn/phpipam
 ---> 5385f0cfaf12
Step 2/3 : ADD class.Common.php /var/www/html/functions/classes/
 ---> b5e288da30ef
Step 3/3 : CMD ["echo","Patch Fix #2440 applied"]
 ---> Running in 6738048b3ae1
Removing intermediate container 6738048b3ae1
 ---> 989fdb6c8c8a

Successfully built 989fdb6c8c8a
Successfully tagged patch-2440_ipam2440:latest
WARNING: Image for service ipam2440 was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Creating patch-2440_mysql_1 ... done
Creating patch-2440_ipam2440_1 ... done
Attaching to patch-2440_mysql_1, patch-2440_ipam2440_1
mysql_1     | 2019-03-22 10:47:13 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
mysql_1     | 2019-03-22 10:47:13 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.6.43) starting as process 1 ...
mysql_1     | 2019-03-22 10:47:13 1 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysql_1     | 2019-03-22 10:47:13 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
mysql_1     | 2019-03-22 10:47:13 1 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
mysql_1     | 2019-03-22 10:47:13 1 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
mysql_1     | 2019-03-22 10:47:13 1 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
mysql_1     | 2019-03-22 10:47:13 1 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
mysql_1     | 2019-03-22 10:47:13 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
mysql_1     | 2019-03-22 10:47:13 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
mysql_1     | 2019-03-22 10:47:13 1 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
mysql_1     | 2019-03-22 10:47:13 1 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
ipam2440_1  | Patch Fix #2440 applied
mysql_1     | 2019-03-22 10:47:14 1 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
mysql_1     | 2019-03-22 10:47:14 1 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
mysql_1     | 2019-03-22 10:47:14 1 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
mysql_1     | 2019-03-22 10:47:14 1 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.43 started; log sequence number 3398964
mysql_1     | 2019-03-22 10:47:14 1 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
mysql_1     | 2019-03-22 10:47:14 1 [Note] IPv6 is available.
mysql_1     | 2019-03-22 10:47:14 1 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
mysql_1     | 2019-03-22 10:47:14 1 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
mysql_1     | 2019-03-22 10:47:14 1 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
mysql_1     | 2019-03-22 10:47:14 1 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@e1de09823bf2' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1     | 2019-03-22 10:47:14 1 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
mysql_1     | 2019-03-22 10:47:14 1 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
mysql_1     | Version: '5.6.43'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
patch-2440_ipam2440_1 exited with code 0
```

Comment: `CMD ["echo", ...]` explicitly tells Docker "instead of the thing you were doing before, when the container starts, print the message then exit".  You probably mean `RUN` here.

Comment: If you're just trying to inject a configuration file (not "patching" an existing file but replacing it or adding a new one), a `volumes:` bind mount could also be an easier setup than building a custom image.

Comment: Thx @DavidMaze that's was my error! And it's not a configuration file but a php file with custom code in it. It will replace the original file.